# NLog compatible with common.logging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nlog

In an existing C# 2008 application, I want to use nLog open source for its logging capabilities. In this application common.logging wrapper is already being used.
Thus can you tell me if nLog is compatible with common.logging? If so, can  you tell me and/or point me to references on how to have these two features work with each other?
If nLog is not compatible with common.logging, can you tell me what other open source .net logging tool is compatible with common.logging?

Comment: This question is also answered (and up-to-date) on the FAQ: https://github.com/NLog/NLog#frequently-asked-questions-faq

Answer (score 0):

[Common.Logging](http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/) supports both NLog 1.0 and 2.0 according to its web site.